# MVC Decimal? Incremental Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-validation

Is it possible, in addition to adding a range to an decimal? apply increments such as only divisible by 100 to be true?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Amount is Required")]
[Range(1000, 25000, ErrorMessage = "Loan must be between 1000 and 25000")]
[DisplayName("Amount")]
public decimal? amount { get; set; }
```

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Nothing out of the box that will do that. You need to write your own validation attribute

Comment: So maybe a controller function on HttpPost that will check if the amount is divisible by 100 and if not apply a ModelState Error perhaps?

Comment: A custom validation attribute will allow you to apply it to other properties and give you client side validation as well, but if you don't need/want that, then adding a `ModelState` error in the controller would be fine.

Comment: you can have a private field and use  "Compare " with that.. :)